# How to deploy script across a domain having Linux systems

Tags: linux, shell, ldap, redhat

Scenario: There is a Linux server (RHEL 5.0) and around 500 end-user computers running Linux OS. I want to connect all these systems in one domain & would like to further execute shell scripts on those 500 computers.

The motive of executing the shell scripts will be to remotely install package/check the packages installed/files residing on end user systems. How can I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/19010/89963

Comment: 1. This question should be asked on serverfault.com, superuser.com or unix.stackexchange.com. Please don't take it personally that it's going to be closed on SO. 2. I believe, there should be a more complete list of tasks you're going to need; for start, you need a user authentication method for all the hosts. Can you come up with a more precise 3. The Google search "linux alternative to Windows domain" gives a lot of interesting reading, like this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/333/54895

Comment: Thanks bzeaman & Victor. The way we push executable scripts through "Active Directory" server on all the systems in domain. In the similar way, I want to know if there is anything like "Active Directory" component which I can configure and execute a shell script on the end-user systems in domain.